# Add coordinates to google Maps in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

How can I add coordinates to google maps "center" when working with angular framework.
I have coordinates displace on my page with

```
coordinates: <td>{{lat}},{{lng}}</td>
```

I have the below code which does not work, where am I going wrong?

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
```

I get the following error with this

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>
> Syntax Error: Token 'latitude' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
>   Below is the controller from which the values of the coordinates are obtained:

```
.controller('UncatCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

$http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8000/getuncategorisedplaces').success(function (data, status, headers) {

    $scope.places = data;
    console.log(data);
    $scope.message = 'Uncategorised places';
})
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.showplace = function(id) {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://94.125.132.253:8000/getitemdata?ID=' + $scope.id}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.place = data;               //set view model
          console.log(data);

          console.log(id);

           $scope.view = 'templates/detail.html';
          console.log(data.place.lat);
  $scope.map =
{
center: {
  latitude : data.place.lat,
   longitude : data.place.lng,

 },
zoom: 13,

}
```

Comment: {latitude:{latitude}} you are going wrong here. Probably should be {latitude:{{latitude}}

Comment: That does that recoganise angular for some reason. <google-map tag does not recoganise my angular values

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: on your controlller create a variable that will hold the entire string value of the attribute and then bind to it.

```
$scope.centerCoords = '[{latitude:' + $scope.latitude + '},longitude:{'+ $scope.latitude + '}]'
```

(I´m not familiar with the google maps sintax, so please forgive me if the above code ins´t accurate, just fix it if that´s the case)

And then bind it like this:

```
<google-map center="{{centerCoords}}" zoom="zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
```

By the way, is the google-map a custom directive?

Comment: No it is not a custom directive, i have imported a module and included angular google maps js file. Also, what is $scope.latitude?

Comment: I´m assuming that you have an angular controller with those properties, if that´s not the case, please share some more code with us

Comment: I have managed to print the values of the latitude and longitude using the javascript you provided so when I do console.log($scope.centerCoords) I get {latitude:51.753589,longitude:-1.258544}, but it does not work in html again

Comment: there seems to be a problem with google map tag not linking to my angualr at all

Comment: what if you specifically assign a controller to that element using ng-controller?

Comment: I think the problem is deeper, the fact that the value is not available to the google-map tag must be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<google-map center="[{latitude:{{latitude}},longitude:{{longitudes}}}]" zoom="zoom" draggable="true" options="options">`

Comment: No that does not work, it is taking latitude as a value rather than taking latitudes value from angualr

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you have mentioned. Are you asking me to provide to link to the code?

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS Google Map directive works in a way which won't evaluate your expression in the center attribute. Please see the [official documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) for more information and fix your code doing the following:

```
 // in your UncatCtrl make the following object
 $scope.map = 
 {
  center: {
   latitude: $scope.latitude, 
   longitude: $scope.longitude 
  }, 
  zoom: 14
 };

 // in your google-map html element use
 <google-map center="map.center" ...></google-map>
```

Here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/m8n9x5xn/

Comment: I have tried that I get no errors inconsole. But the value of center when inspected shows map.center hence the map doesn't laod

Comment: You already have $scope.map defined in your code too, please make sure everything is fine there. This example is taken from the official documentation so it is likely to work fine when done right.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am going to edit the post showing my current code

Comment: I don't know, works like a charm. Please refresh my fiddle it even has your GET code in it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59412/discussion-between-henrik-peinar-and-roxci-william).